# How do I call a Postgres function server-side?

Tags: supabase

How do I call a Postgres function server-side?

It seems that RPC only works client-side https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/rpc

```
const { data, error } = await supabase.rpc('hello_world')
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that it works, but also throws an error https://github.com/supabase/supabase/issues/18007

Answer (score 0):

```
const { Client } = require('pg');
const client = new Client();

async function main() {
  await client.connect();
  const res = await client.query('SELECT hello_world()');
  console.log(res.rows[0]);
  await client.end();
}

main();
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**